# How do I return a Future<double> in a ListView with Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to get a `Future<double>` into a listview using the Provider package, but have been unsuccessful.  Can anyone give me some advice or a link that explains how to implement `notifylisteners()` on a Future that returns a double?

Here is the Future of `getPrice()`:

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stock_watchlist/stock_service.dart';

class StockData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Stock> _stocks = [
    Stock(symbol: 'AAPL'),
    Stock(symbol: 'AMD'),
    Stock(symbol: 'TSLA')
  ];

  UnmodifiableListView<Stock> get stocks {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_stocks);
  }

  int get stockCount {
    return _stocks.length;
  }

  void addStock(String symbol, double price, double eps) {
    final stock = Stock(symbol: symbol);
    _stocks.add(stock);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void deleteStock(Stock stock) {
    _stocks.remove(stock);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<double> getPrice(String symbol) async {
    String url =
        "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/$symbol/quote/latestPrice?token=Tsk_38ddda0b877a4510b42a37ae713cdc96";

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    double price = double.tryParse(response.body);
    return price;
  }

  Future<double> getEps(String symbol) async {
    String url =
        "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/$symbol/stats/ttmEPS?token=Tsk_38ddda0b877a4510b42a37ae713cdc96";

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    double eps = double.tryParse(response.body);
    return eps;
  }
}
```

Here is where I am trying to input the value of `getPrice()` into a text widget but it is giving me "Instance of `Future<double>`" instead of the value.

[image: I cannot embed pictures yet]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:stock_watchlist/constants.dart';
import 'package:stock_watchlist/stock_model.dart';

class StockList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<StockData>(
      builder: (context, stockData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: stockData.stockCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            //
            final stockIndex = stockData.stocks[index];
            //
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                stockIndex.symbol,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: kTextColor,
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                stockIndex.price.toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: kTextColor,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `FutureBuilder`? You can try to make the builder function `async` and then `final stockIndex = await stockData.stocks[index]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I think I figured it out with FutureBuilder.  Here is the code I used.

```
class StockList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<StockData>(
      builder: (context, stockData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: stockData.stockCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            //
            final stockIndex = stockData.stocks[index];
            //
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                stockIndex.symbol,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: kTextColor,
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: FutureBuilder(
                future: stockData.getPrice(stockIndex.symbol),
                builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
                  snapshot.data.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: kTextColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```